# Where is "Choose columns to display" in phpMyAdmin 4?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know that "choose columns to display" can be found under relational view of a particular table. I am using phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 and that feature is not visible with this version under relational view. I have two tables in a small database and both tables have innoDB storage engine.

Where have I gone wrong? Why cannot I see that feature? Is not is supported by phpMyAdmin anymore or something wrong from my side? If so what are possible reasons?

Answer (score -2):

Try clicking the down arrow just to the right of the large "T", in the top right of the browse table. This should offer a drop-down where you can select which columns you want to display.